# How to use @HiltAndroidApp annotation but there's no Application class in the project?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

As Android documentation said:

> All apps that use Hilt must contain an `Application` class that is annotated with `@HiltAndroidApp`

When I create an Android project from template (Tabs template of Android Studio) it seems not to provide any `Application` class but `class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()` instead. So how can I use Hilt in this project?

I have tried this:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    ...
}
```

But it didn't work :<

Comment: `it seems not to provide any Application class` so then make the application class yourself ? there are loads of resources online explaining how to do this, you could have just researched `how to create application class android` and found loads of resources

Comment: You should create a class that inherit from Application and add it in manifest. application class is the main place where dagger or hilt load dependencies tree and do some initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Your `MainActivity` is not the `Application` class.

For activities use the `@AndroidEntryPoint`. See more on https://dagger.dev/hilt/android-entry-point

The annotation `@HiltAndroidApp` is for the `Application` class. See more on https://dagger.dev/hilt/application